# How to know if numbers in a list follow an ascending numerical order (eg: 1,2,3,4,5 etc.) without skipping any number

Tags: python

Got the following lists:

```
example_one = [1, 7, 3]
example_two = [1, 3, 4, 2]
example_three = [2, 3, 5]
example_four = [13, 14, 15]
```

Need to make a function that returns True if it follows the ascending numeric order (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9... etc.) without skipping any number, else return False:

```
False
True
False
True
```

Note that in example 2 the output is true, the numbers contained on the list don't need to be in a specific order since they can be sorted.

Comment: What is the expected output for `[1,2,2,3]`?

Comment: @Chris In the code I need to apply this function there's no possible way of getting the same numbers twice, the numbers inside the list cannot be deleted, moved, cloned, etc. they're just in there until the code stops running.

Comment: Could you sort then subtract the first number from the last then add 1 and compare to length of the list? `if example_four[-1] - example_four[0] + 1 == len(example_four): True`

Comment: Shouldn't the answer by `False, True, True, True`.  `example_one = 1,7,3` and does not have any ascending order numbers. `example_two = 1, 3, 4, 2`. This has `3, 4` in ascending order so i assume it is `True`. Similarly `example_three` has `2, 3` in ascending so `True`. And `example_four` is anyway `True`. Do you agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, one way using `range`:

```
def is_range(eg):
    srt = sorted(eg)
    return srt == list(range(srt[0], srt[0] + len(srt)))

examples = [example_one, example_two, example_three, example_four]
for example in examples:
    print(is_range(example))
```

Output:

```
False
True
False
True
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility could be to perform following checks:

- does list contain any elements
- are list elements unique
- does sum of elements equal to sum of consecutive numbers

If all conditions are not satisfied, then the numbers are not sequential.

```
def sequential(list_):
    if list_:
        if len(set(list_)) == len(list_):
            if sum(list_) == len(list_) * (min(list_) / 2 + max(list_) / 2):
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also check if the difference between first and last number is same as length of the list, then the list has ascending order. Or you can check if the first element + length of element is same as last element + 1.

```
examples = [example_one,example_two,example_three, example_four]

def chk(y):
    return y[-1]-y[0] == len(y)-1

for e in examples:
    e.sort()
    print(chk(e))
```

Alternate, you can use this code to get the same output without a function.

```
examples = [example_one,example_two,example_three, example_four]

for e in examples:
    e.sort()
    x = True if e[0]+len(e) == e[-1]+1 else False
    #or check if length of list is same as difference between first and last element
    #x = True if e[-1]-e[0] == len(e)-1 else False
    print(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

Just sort the list and check if the sorted list is equal to the original like this:

```
def check_if_ascending(arr):
    if sorted(arr) == arr:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Very simple.  But doesn't test the "without skipping any number" requirement.

Comment: BTW, when you want to return `bool` based on `if`, you can just do `return sorted(arr) == arr` instead of `if`-`else` ;)